# Making Cursor Mouse Always Enabled In Unity CardBoard Plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

i think the title is clear , i want to make the mouse Cursor which is set in GazeInpuModule to be always enabled and in center of the both Left And Right Cameras , can anyone help me ?!

- ive tried changing the GazeInputModule code to place the cursor in center , but got nothing !

Comment: Please add your code snippet of what you tried

Comment: just changed the SetActive function of cursor object to true , the problem is the cursor doesnt go deactive but it doesnt get it place in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Create a Cursor GameObject in the Head hierarchy

   [image: Add Cursor GameObject]
2. Add EventSystem in the project hierarchy
3. In the EventSystem Gaze Input Module component, ensure "Show Cursor" is selected.

   [image: Show Cursor checkbox select]
4. In GazeInputModule.cs, PlaceCursor(), change the SetActive() to:

   ```
   private void PlaceCursor() {
       // ...
       cursor.SetActive(showCursor); 
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: I add an empty gameobject to scene. I click the object in hierarchy, I add GazeInputModule on inspector. There is no "show cursor"  option. I open GazeInputModule.cs file, it doesn't include "PlaceCursor" function.