# Google Cardboard - How to detect focus on an object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, focus, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I try to create a VR scene in unity using google cardboard sdk. I add a cube and CardboardMain.prefab to scene. There is an example scene that detect focus on cube. Its hierarchy view is :

[image]

I don't know how to add GUIReticle object or prefab like as the image.

How can I detect focus on an object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Cursor Mouse Always Enabled In Unity CardBoard Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095680/making-cursor-mouse-always-enabled-in-unity-cardboard-plugin)

Comment: No duplicate. I tried this solution but it didin't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you could make the script by your own and it is quite simple.

You could detect whether the user is looking at your object or not by using `RayCast` from the Main Camera. If the `RayCast` hit your object, then it is being focused on.

For example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
public class LookableObject : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    Transform cam; // This is the main camera.
    // You can alternately use Camera.main if you've tagged it as MainCamera

    bool focus; // True if focused

    Collider gazeArea; // Your object's collider

    public void Start () {
        gazeArea = GetComponent<Collider> ();
    }

    public void Update () {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast (cam.position, cam.forward, out hit, 1000f)) {
            focus = (hit.collider == gazeArea);    
        } else {
            focus = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This is just an example. You probably would want to make a script to do the Raycast only just once instead of doing the Raycast on each of your object over and over again to make your project runs faster.